# Can someone explain what is happening in the below snipped of code? I am trying to understand the below Scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def expr(myCols: Set[String], allCols: Set[String]) =
  allCols.toList.map {
    case x if myCols.contains(x) => col(x)
    case x => lit(null).as(x)
  }
```

Comment: What you do not understand?

Comment: I think learning Scala is a sad necessity in your case. Unless you want to run each piece of code you run across through SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method returns a list of [Columns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html), and some of the columns are set to `null` when you use this list to select columns from a data frame.

`allCols` should contain all columns of a data frame, and `myCols` should contain the columns that you want keep. All other columns not contained in `myCols`will be set to `null`:

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))).toDF("a","b","c")
df.show
val columns = expr(Set("a"), df.columns.toSet)
df.select(columns:_*).show
```

will print

```
 +---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+

+---+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+
|  1|null|null|
|  4|null|null|
|  7|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

Inside of your method, each entry of `allCols` is either mapped to an actual column or to a `null` literal by using Scala's [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) magic.